# How to define a public static method with a collection param in C++/CX?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, interop, c++-cx

How to define a public static method with param is a collection (vector or map) ?
(Then, I need C# in WP8 to call this method)

i wrote:

```
public ref class TestClass sealed
{
public:
static void Test(Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<int> ^ s);
static void Test1(Platform::Collections::Vector<int> ^ s);
}
```

then, both Test and Test1 compile with errors.

> error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl WPRuntimeComponent::delegateTest::Test(struct Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector ^)" (?Test@delegateTest@WPRuntimeComponent@@SAXP$AAU?$IVector@H@Collections@Foundati‌​on@Windows@@@Z)

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl WPRuntimeComponent::delegateTest::Test(struct Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<int> ^)" (?Test@delegateTest@WPRuntimeComponent@@SAXP$AAU?$IVector@H@Collections@Foundation@Windows@@@Z)

Comment: Retagged your question, so other people might find it, too... From what I can tell, have you provided a bdy for the method? Here you declared, but haven't defined anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this code.

1. The method test doesn't have a body therefore the linker error
2. The method Test1 is a public method of a ref class which means it can use only Windows Runtime types in its signature whereas this method has a param of the type Platform::Collections::Vector, which is not a proper Windows Runtime type, but happens to be just a helper native type defined in a header file